# Note: Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued. It will attempt to resume at a later time.

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Since some time when I run workflow I see this "Note: Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued. It will attempt to resume at a later time."

This is very simple workflow which I did in SharePoint Designer and SP Farm is also quite small and simple. Server resources are also at good level.

I did advices from below blog but it doesn't solve my issue.

http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-improve-workflow-performance-in.html

I use SharePoint Foundation and SP Designer 2010.

Could somebody has any ideas to solve it?

I will be very thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you correctly implemented all configuration changes mentioned in the link you provided, then only option I can think is to add more RAM and\or CPU to your server.

Comment: But memory is used only in 50% and CPU in 10%-15% and notfing is happens with resurces when I trigger workflow...

Comment: see the usage on your DB server